# In Pentaho Kettle, how to generate formatted date for parameter for Google Analytics API?

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I've successfully created a Pentaho transformation to retrieve data for a single day via the Google Analytics API and pipe it into MySQL. I now want to automate the job, running it every day to retrieve yesterday's data.

I've set up ${STARTDATE} and ${ENDDATE} parameters to drive the GA query, but I'm not clear on how to generate the proper date-formatted string.

Example:
On 10/18/2014, generate: "2014-10-17" and place it into ${STARTDATE} and ${ENDDATE}

Based on Googling around, I found something that I adapted to this as the default value for both parameters, which doesn't work:
=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-1) + '-' + MONTH(TODAY()-1) + '-' + DAY(TODAY()-1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a get parameters step and format the dates. Look here for more info on the get variable step:

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Get+Variable

Look at the code sample in the link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwwXJ3GUloGURlRpbFg3TUQ5Rkk/view?usp=sharing

This is just one way to do it though. I'm sure you'll be able to simplify it for your code.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Fantastic stuff. Thanks so much. The only simplification I made was to simply use ${STARTDATE} and {$ENDDATE} directly in the Google Analytics step of the "process data" job. For the benefit of others finding this, the solution used was two transformations. First uses Generate Rows | Get System Info (I got yesterday's date) | Format Dates | Copy rows to result. Second transformation is the actual data processing job with Google Analytics. Tie them together in a job and voila!